# How to merge mongodbs (same collection)?

Tags: mongodb

Sometimes we may want to merge the collections because accidents or simply trying to reduce redundancy.

For example if I have collection-a on machine 1 and collection-a on machine 2 as such:

collection-a (machine 1)

```
a: 123
b: 321
c: 456
```

collection-a (machine 2)

```
a: 123
b: 321
d: 789
```

I want to merge them into:

```
a: 123
b: 321
c: 456
d: 789
```

I can iterate through one collection's records and add them to another collection so that I can merge them but that would take about 7 hours since the network speed between these two machine is limited - and the collections are fairly large. Are there other methods that I can use to merge collections quickly?

Comment: You may consider a ReplicaSet.

Comment: When the two collections are hosted by different machines then it cannot be the "same" collection.

Comment: If these two collections are on different clusters/servers then you can use `mongodump` to dump the data from one collection & import data to another collection using `mongorestore` rather than reading & writing thru code..